# Como fazer verificação de qualquer tipo recebido (maiúsculas ou minúsculas)?

Tags: c++

Como posso fazer com que sejam ignoradas as maiúsculas e minúsculas para comparar com palavra predefinida?

Ex: stack(palavra predefinida para comparar)

Palavras que poderiam ser recebidas: "sTAck" "STACk"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simples: converta o texto para maiúscula e compare. Exemplo de código em C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool compare(string s1, string s2)
{
    transform(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s1.begin(), ::toupper);
    transform(s2.begin(), s2.end(), s2.begin(), ::toupper);
    return s1 == s2;
}

int main() {

    string s[] = {"sTAck", "STACk", "STAcK", "SSTTAACCKK", "stack", "Extack"};

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        cout << s[i] << (compare(s[i], "stack") ? " OK" : " NOK") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Resultado:

```
sTAck OK
STACk OK
STAcK OK
SSTTAACCKK NOK
stack OK
Extack NOK
```

Veja executando [no Ideone](http://ideone.com/CrJRvF).

Answer (score 2):

Não conheço muito de C++, mas se você não precisar manter a formatação da forma como foi digitada poderia utilizar um método para transformar letras em maiúsculas, se não me engano C++ usa o método toupper(var) para retornar uma string em uppercase (se não me engano).

Estou mais familiarizado com python, então uso o seguinte:

```
a = "olamundo".upper() #para maiúsculas
```

ou:

```
a = "OLAMUNDO".lower() #para minúsculas
```

Espero ter ajudado.

ps: você poderia armazenar em outra variável o valor do método e usar a variável inicial para manter a formatação.

para referência:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/75634/

Answer (score 1):

Não existe uma função nativa de comparação case-insensitive de strings no C++.
No Windows você poderia usar "stricmp" e no Linux "strcasecmp".
Em C++ puro é preciso um pouquinho de código adicional.

Abaixo, uma maneira de como poderia ser feita essa comparação em C++ puro, usando o algoritmo genérico "mismatch" e a função "toupper".

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const string compare(const string& s1, string const& s2)
{
   if (s1.size() != s2.size()) return "diferentes";

   auto result = mismatch(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),
      [](char c1, char c2) { return ::toupper(c1) == ::toupper(c2); });

   return result.first == s1.end() ? "iguais" : "diferentes";
}

int main()
{
   vector<string> s { "sTAck", "STACk", "STAcK", "SSTTAACCKK", "stack", "xxx" };

   for (const auto& str : s)
       cout << str << ": " << compare(str, "stack") << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Porquê a referencia (&) no ciclo e qual a necessidade ?

Comment: Sem a referência a variável "str" será uma cópia do elemento do vetor; com a referência a variável "str" será o próprio elemento do vetor. Se é necessário ou não, depende do contexto. Se o loop **não** vai alterar o elemento do vetor então a a referência **não** é necessária, mas mesmo assim usa-se a referência para evitar cópias desnecessárias.

Comment: Esclarecido. Caso o loop esteja numa função essa copia seria imediatamente apagada depois da função ser executada correcta ?

Comment: A cópia existiria apena no escopo do comando "for".